# Why I can't delete this question

Tags: support

[How do I add a patch to patches in composer.json from the command line?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317377/how-do-i-add-a-patch-to-patches-in-composer-json-from-the-command-line)

after the *warm welcome* I received on the other question which I deleted already, I don't think I want to share any more, no thanks.

I get an error saying "you cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it"

but they didn't, I answered it myself because I am an old fool who overshares

Comment: I would not have deleted the other answer simply because somebody does not agree that 3 in 3.2 is also indicating the branch. Yes, it is true that somebody could create a 3.2 release from a 4.x branch, but that is not what usually happens with projects hosted on drupal.org.

Comment: no, I deleted because of the downvote. and somewhat because of the condescending comment too.

Comment: A single down-vote does not count. You should have ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

The system doesn’t allow you to delete posts which have been positively voted upon, as it indicates the community find value in them; it’s the same on all Stack Exchange sites.

If you don’t want to remain associated with the question you’re welcome to contact Stack Exchange directly and request a disassociation (link at the bottom of the page). They will remove your name and avatar from the post.

They’re not likely to delete the content, though, as the license which you agreed to post the content under protects them from having to do so, and as I said, valuable content doesn’t get deleted.

Comment: Truly, the license does not forbid that answers are deleted. In fact, questions posted as answers are deleted, even if the license would be equally valid for those "answers" too.

Comment: Correct, the license exists so they don’t _have_ to delete it, for any reason, if they don’t want to. I thought I made that clear but I’ll reword it in a bit if it’s ambiguous

Comment: In fact, they will not delete a question posted as answer because that would be done by a moderator. **`;-)`**

Comment: Jokes apart, Stack Exchange does not accept requests to delete content because Stack Exchange sites are seen as a collective work. Stack Exchange does not consider single questions for which the same person who asked the question posted an answer too.